# Strongly typed XML not working with XSLT/XSL when using xml.transformNode(xml)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm pretty green with XSLT but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

I'm using xml.transformNode(...) ([found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to try and do a basic XSLT display.

**My XML:**

```
<Table:Record name="CustTable" xmlns:Table='urn:www.microsoft.com/Formats/Table'>
    <Table:Field name="AccountNum">100000</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="Name">Test Account</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="createdDateTime">7/11/2008 03:52:56 pm</Table:Field>
    <Table:Field name="recVersion">443580233</Table:Field>
</Table:Record>
```

**My Non-Working XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match"/Table:Record name="CustTable">
<html>
<body>
   <xsl:for-each select="record">
       <xsl:value-of select="field" /><br />
   </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What are you wanting the result to look like? I can see a number of issues but I'm not sure how best to direct you.

Comment: Just dumping out the XML values.  As simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:Table="urn:www.microsoft.com/Formats/Table">
    <!-- Included the xmlns (XML name space) for Table-->
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <!-- Told it to output html -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- started at / to override any other rules -->
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="//Table:Record[@name='CustTable']">
                    <!-- note the change in selector to use single quotes -->
                    <p>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Table:Field">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            <br/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How did you know to put `urn:www.microsoft.com/Formats/Table`

Comment: It would have worked in my environment with `xmlns:Table="fred"`, as the key part was to let there be a reference for the `Table` namespace. In some environments it might be important to have the correct reference attached; I copied it from the supplied XML.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an idea of how XSLT really works. You need to

- match elements *together with* their namespace (in this case: Table)
- to use single quotes, if they are enclosed by double quotes
- preface an attribute by `@` or `attribute::`
- be very precise about the names of elements. There is no element named `record` or `field` in the input XML you have shown

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:Table='urn:www.microsoft.com/Formats/Table'>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="Table"/>

<xsl:template match="/Table:Record[@name='CustTable']">
  <html>
     <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Table:Field">
            <xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
        </xsl:for-each>
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This explains a ton.  So with `<xsl:value-of select="." />`, does the `.` act as a wildcard?

Comment: @AlexK The period is a way of saying "this current node". The current node in this case either being what is used in your template match or your for-each select, depending on where you use it.

Comment: It gives a correct result only with the XML input snippet you have shown. If your actual input XML has a different structure, you need to adjust the stylesheet.